# setting the date format in php WP plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I know this probably isn't as easy to answer when you don't have all the various files at hand. But I'm just wondering could someone offer a clue as to where I could look for somewhere to change the format of the date in the wordpress plugin (leaguemanager).

In a table I have `echo $match->date." "`

I have looked around and found this in another file in  a for loop...

```
$match->date = ( substr($match->date, 0, 10) == '0000-00-00' ) ? 'N/A' :         
mysql2date(get_option('date_format'), $match->date);
```

I know this is a bit vague, but I'm still in the early days of learning php and am more so just looking for a clue as to what I should be looking for, rather than an actual answer itself, I know how to change date formats with php, but I just don't where to find this particular one to change.
At the moments its showing as September 28, 2012 , I just want d m , which would be 28/09

EDIT: one more bit of info I found in a file called ajax.php

```
$date_format = $_POST['date_format'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
echo date('j/m', strtotime($match->date));
```

reference to date formats: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks JvdBerg , that worked perfectly. Just for the sake of learning, may I ask, was the original date simply a default one that php uses if the strtotime function isnt used? Or is it a case that the original format might have been still declared somewhere amongst the files of the plugin?

Comment: I do not understand your question, but I think you mean where $match->date came from?

Comment: Not really, I was moreso wondering where the original date format came from, the one before I changed it, thanks

Comment: ahh .. ok. That one came from a function `mysql2date` inside WP. Probably doing something alike my answer :)